# Can the attributes of a class be an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, class, attributes

I'm new to OOP, so please bear with me if this is a simple question. If I create a class, which has attributes "a", "b", and "c", is it possible for the attributes to be an array, such that attribute a[2] has a meaning?

Comment: What is an attribute? You mean member variable?

Comment: C++ uses the term member variable, in UML they are called attributes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Member variables can ofcourse be arrays. Example:

```
class MyClass {
    int a[3];  // Array containing three ints
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that by "attributes" you mean what C++ refers to as "member variables" (i.e. members of a particular objects):

```
class MyClass:
public:
    MyClass() {
       a.push_back(3);
       a.push_back(4);
       a.push_back(5);
       cout << a[2] << endl; // should output "5"
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> a;
};
```

Comment: Ok, but a `std::vector` is not an array.

Comment: @Jesper - fair point. I just figured that was possibly a helpful way to go for someone new to C++.